# WSO2 - Security patches link / location

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using WSO2 open source products : Identity server and enterprise integrator / micro integrator. Where can i get the security patches available so that i can apply them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a subscription holder, you can get the security patches from WSO2 Update Manager [1] [2] or else you need to update the product to the latest version to get the fixes.

[1] https://wso2.com/updates

[2] https://wso2.com/security-patch-releases-notice